# How to use libxcb on mac?

Tags: c, x11, xcb

My laptop is Macbook Pro.
I installed libxcb on it and tried a simple example that x.org given:

```
#include <unistd.h>      /* pause() */
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

int main ()
{
    xcb_connection_t *c;
    xcb_screen_t     *screen;
    xcb_window_t      win;

    /* Open the connection to the X server */
    c = xcb_connect (NULL, NULL);

    /* Get the first screen */
    screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator (xcb_get_setup (c)).data;

    /* Ask for our window's Id */
    win = xcb_generate_id(c);

    /* Create the window */
    xcb_create_window (c,                             /* Connection        */
                       XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,          /* depth (same as root)*/
                       win,                           /* window Id           */
                       screen->root,                  /* parent window       */
                       0, 0,                          /* x, y                */
                       150, 150,                      /* width, height       */
                       10,                            /* border_width        */
                       XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT, /* class               */
                       screen->root_visual,           /* visual              */
                       0, NULL);                      /* masks, not used yet */

    /* Map the window on the screen */
    xcb_map_window (c, win);

    /* Make sure commands are sent before we pause, so window is shown */
    xcb_flush (c);

    pause ();    /* hold client until Ctrl-C */

    return 0;
}
```

But there is no window shown on screen. Is there something I forget?

Comment: What are your `#include`s? How do you compile it?

Comment: Is there an X11 icon bouncing in the dock? On my iMac 2013-ish X11 applications start up extremely slowly, sometimes no window is shown for minutes, but there is the X11 icon in the dock.

Comment: I compile it by this command: cc -Wall -o a a.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb`

No icon in the dock

Comment: Should I install a x-server? I tried but xorg-server relied on libdrm which would encounter an error that complier cannot find <sys/endian.h>. It seems like I should also install glibc, but glibc do not support Darwin.

Comment: and why the width and height in xcb_screen_t are all zero...?

Comment: Thank you all guys, it's resolved. xcb_connect() has an error, it needs the first argument or an env variable DISPLAY. I don't have anyone of them. So I install a XQuartz (a x-server), reboot os, then DISPLAY has a value and program can be executed correctly.